# Add less specific class without !important

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have the following CSS rules:

```
.bookItem:hover { background: rgba(0,150,255,0.1); }

.selected { background: rgba(0,150,255,0.2) !important; }
```

When a bookItem is clicked, I use jQuery to add the selected class to it.  The trouble is, without the `!important` the selected class does not show until the mouse is no longer hovering.  I know this is because the :hover pseudoclass makes this selector "more specific".

Is it possible to change the `.selected` class to cause it to take higher precedence than :bookItem:hover *without* the `!important`?

Comment: show the HTML so we know what you're selecting.

Comment: it is possible, if you know how CSS handles precednce. I am a little rusty, but I believe the lowest precedence is from external styles (that is files), then internal styles (css files in your domain's server), and then inline styles (although this is looked down upon). Someone correct me, because I might be wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, in my opinion, you should reconsider using this css keyword at all. !important is a tool too powerful and it mainly destroys all the hierarchy css has, making it very difficult to debug your code. Its usage should be restricted to a small number of extreme examples when there is no way out.

Again, in my opinion, you should try to use as many html tags as possible, then use classes and ids, and lastly the specific atributes on css. I would go with the composed class like my fellows suggested:

```
.bookitem.selected { back... ; }
```

Finally, for additional information, you can read [this post at smashing magazine](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/02/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to change the specificity of `.selected` to `.bookItem.selected`

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/WK34y/

Answer (score 2):

to make `.selected` class more general so it can be anywhere and not only on `.bookItem` elements, it worked for me forcing the `.selected` style on hover

```
.selected,.selected:hover { background: rgba(0,150,255,0.2)}
```

[a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/uT5TU/)

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem of specificity.  In you stylesheet define .selected like this

```
div item#books .selected {bacground: rgba(0,150,255,0.2);}
```

http://css-tricks.com/855-specifics-on-css-specificity/

Comment: it's possible that you can just increase the specificity by 1 but I am not sure what the predecessors specificity is so I'm going overkill.